# Can I connect a normal RCA cable to my XBOX 360 E to get video?

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

I want to connect my XBOX 360E to my TV that only has RCA(A/V) inputs and TV signal inputs. I lost my XBOX RCA cable. And I cannot buy a new XBOX one.

I bought a standard one but it did not work. I don't know if the cable is faulty or its just not compatible.

If it isn't compatible. Maybe I can make it compatible? How?

#### Update

If I insert the 3.5mm jack only partially into my XBOX I am able to get video. But the audio doesn't work. But I can get audio if I insert my headphone jack into it.

So might just be that its not compatible. Maybe if I changed the soldering in some way it might just work.

Where can I find the pinouts for the 3.5mm jack?

Comment: What exactly is "a normal one"?

Comment: One I could buy at my local hardware store. I can also use it on my walkman and tv card. I should have said standard.

Comment: Turn the Xbox on via the controller, and hold left trigger & Y. This resets your display settings to the most basic.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 3.5mm Composite AV cable for Xbox 360 E.

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/connect-xbox-360e-console-tv